# Paginate from within a model in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-1.3, pagination

I have a function in my `Event` model called `getEvents` - you can pass limit, `start` and `end` dates, `fields`, `event` `types`, and event `subtypes`.

I read that `paginate` can accept all the parameters I'm using like `joins`, `conditions`, `limit`...etc just like a normal `find` can.

It returns data just fine when I don't try to paginate.  But - I'd like to be able to pass it a `paginate` variable to tell it instead of doing this:

```
$this->recursive = -1;
$data = $this->find('all', $qOptions);
```

to do this:

```
$this->recursive = -1;
$data = $this->paginate($qOptions);
```

When I try that, though, it gives me lots of errors.  I can specify the errors later if needed - for now, I guess I'm looking for - is this something that can be done?  If so, how?

Is there another better way to do something like this?  I spent enough time making this function do just what I want, and allowing all the options passed...etc - it just seems like a waste if I can't also use it for pagination.  But - if it's not ideal, I'm ok hearing that too.  Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I'm reading other things online that say you shouldn't use paginate in your model, because it draws from URL variables, which defeats the MVC structure purpose.  This makes sense, but does that mean I have to write the same joins/queries in both model and controller?  And in every action that it's needed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way I figured out how I can keep my complex `find` in my model without having to rewrite it a second time in the controller is by passing a `$paginate` boolean variable.

If `$paginate` is true, it returns just the options created, which can then be used in the controller's pagination.  If it's false (meaning we don't want to paginate), it returns the actual event results.  So far this seems to be working.

In my `getEvents()` function (this method is in the Events model)

```
    if($paginate) {
        return $qOpts; // Just return the options for the paginate in the controller to use
    } else {
        $data = $this->find('all', $qOpts); // Return the actual events
        return $data;
    }
```

Then, in my Events/Index (events controller, index action - where I know I want pagination):

```
$this->Event->recursive = -1; // (or set recursive = -1 in the appModel)
$opts['paginate'] = true;

$paginateOptions = $this->Event->getEvents($opts);

$this->paginate = $paginateOptions; // Set paginate options to just-returned options
$data = $this->paginate('Event'); // Get paginate results
$this->set('data', $data); // Set variable to hold paginated results in view
```

Answer (score 3):

The `paginate()` model method does *not* accept the same parameters as a `find()`. Specifically, `find()` wants an array of options, but `paginate()` wants every option passed individually. See [Custom Query Pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1237/Custom-Query-Pagination) in the CakePHP book.

So, instead of:

```
$data = $this->paginate($qOptions);
```

You want something like:

```
$data = $this->paginate($qOptions['conditions'], $qOptions['fields'], ...);
```

**EDIT**

Custom model pagination isn't a function that you call. It's a function that you need to implement and will be called by the CakePHP framework. In the example in your question you are trying to manually call `$this->paginate(...)` from somewhere in your model. That doesn't work. Instead, do this.

In your model, implement the `paginate` and `paginateCount` methods.

```
function paginate($conditions, $fields, ...)
{
    // return some data here based on the parameters passed
}

function paginateCount($conditions, ...)
{
    // return some rowcount here based off the passed parameters
}
```

Then, in your controller you can use the standard pagination functions.

```
function index()
{
    $this->paginate = array('MyModel' => array(
        'conditions' => array(...),
        'fields' => array(...),
    ));

    $this->set('myobjects', $this->paginate('MyModel'));
}
```

Now, the `Controller::paginate()` function will grab the conditions and other data from the `Controller::paginate` parameter and, instead of passing it to your `Model::find` it will pass it to your custom `Model::paginate()` and `Model::paginateCount()` functions. So, the data that is returned is based on whatever you do in those two methods and not based on a standard `find()`. 
    }

Comment: Ah, ok - I'll try that, thanks.  So - what's the "norm" on this?  Make 2 different functions, one for paginating results, and one for not?  Or combining into one and just building options different if it's paginate vs find?  Any thoughts/direction is appreciated.  This is likely the answer and will try first thing in the morning - thanks agian!

Comment: @Sander - After trying and trying, I still can't get it to work. I can't even get a straight up normal `$data = $this->paginate();` to work in the model.  When I do, I get `Warning (512): SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'paginate'` and `Query: paginate`

Comment: That error means that your model does not have a `paginate` method. If you read the CakePHP Book link I posted, you can see that you need to implement the `paginate` and `paginateCount` methods yourself. When you created those, your controller pagination logic can automagically use them.

Comment: @sander - the link you posted doesn't actually work - mind fixing that for future users?  thanks!

Comment: The page I found that I believe you were linking to makes no sense to me.  Maybe I'm missing something, but - this seems another example of CakePHP poor documentation.  Any chance you could explain or show an example of how I would use that with relation to my question above?

Comment: The URL works fine, but the CakePHP site need JavaScript (AJAX) to load the proper page. Make sure you have JavaScript on. Also, I have added a pagination example. It's off the top of my head, but it should work (when properly implemented).

Comment: The URL doesn't work fine and is incorrect - it appears you've added an additional !# into the link.  In your example, if I'm calling the paginate from the controller then why do any of that - I could call the paginate from the controller just fine prior to asking this question.  What I was asking is - can I call the paginate from within the model.  It's sounding more and more like the answer is "no, you can't".

Comment: You can, but you still need to implement the `paginate` method yourself. Perhaps it's simpler to just set the `limit` and `offset` parameters on a standard `find` call. That's exactly what the controller pagination does when a model does not implement a custom `paginate` method.

Answer (score -1):

**$paginate** array are similar to the parameters of the Model->find('all') method, that is: conditions, fields, order, limit, page, contain, joins, and recursive.

So you can define your conditions like this :

```
var $paginate = array(
 'Event' => array (...)
 );
```

Or you can also set conditions and other keys in the $paginate array inside your action.

```
 $this->paginate = array(
 'conditions' => array(' ... '),
 'limit' => 10
 );
 $data = $this->paginate('Event');
```

- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html
- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html

R u using `$name = 'Event'` in your controller ?

If we wont mention model name in `$this->paginate()` , it will use model as mentioned in  `$name` otherwise look in `var $uses` array and in that will get Model name (first one )

for e.g `var $uses = array('Model1','Model2');` // $name != mentioned

n you want pagination with respect to **Model2** then you have to specify ModelName in paginate array like `$this->paginate('Model2')` otherwise Model1 will be considered in pagination.

Comment: I do have $name = "Event" in my model and I've tried setting the options as you mentioned, but it still tries to run the sql query "paginate" (which obviously isn't a query).  I assume it's something to do with what sander above said, but can't figure it out

Comment: There's a distinct difference between the `Controller::paginate` parameter, the `Controller::paginate()` method and the `Model::paginate()` method. Dave is asking about the latter. You're talking about the former two.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this one which is working fine for me.

$condition="your where condition";
 $this->paginate = array(
                            'fields' => array('AsinsBookhistory.id', 'AsinsBookhistory.reffer_id', 'AsinsBookhistory.ISBN','AsinsBookhistory.image','AsinsBookhistory.title','AsinsBookhistory.last_updatedtime'),
                            'conditions' => $condition,
                            'group' => array('AsinsBookhistory.ISBN'),
                            'order' => array('AsinsBookhistory.last_updatedtime' => 'desc')
                                );
$this->set('lastvisitedbooks', $this->paginate('AsinsBookhistory'));