# prepare my model to paginate results in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I am finding that in a number of my controller methods I have to paginate results with only one or two conditions changing between methods.  I also needed the option to NOT paginate at times.  As a complete programming newb, I'd like to practice DRY and so went about learning how I can prepare my model for possible pagination before I code in the controller.  I started to build my query in my model based off the answer in  [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501849/paginate-from-within-a-model-in-cakephp).  Unfortunately, the person who asked the question didn't include the first part of their code, so I am really at a loss as how the first part of their model query looks.  When I use the code I have below I get two illegal offset type errors on Model.    Below is my model code:

```
<?php class Unit extends AppModel {
public $name='Unit';
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
public $belongsTo=array(
'User',
'Complex',

'Location',
);

public $hasOne=array(
    'Image'
    );
function getListings() {
    $paginate=array();
        $qOptions=array();
    $this->contain(array(
                    'User'=>array('id'),
                    'Location',
                    'Complex',
                    'Image'
                    )
            );
    if($paginate) {
        return $qOptions;
        }
    else {

        $data= $this->find('all', $qOptions);
        return $data;
    }
}
}
?>
```

here is my controller method:

```
<?php
class LodgingsController extends AppController {
    public $name='Lodgings';

    public $layout='pagelayout';
    public $uses=array('User', 'Unit', 'Location');
    public $helpers=array('Text','Html','Js','GoogleMapV3');

    public $paginate=array();


public function debug() {

   $qOptions=array('conditions'=>array('Unit.active'=>1, 'Unit.type'=>'condo'), 'limit'=>9, 'order'=>array('Unit.id'=>'asc'));
   $opts['paginate'] = true;
   $paginateOptions=$this->Unit->getListings($opts);
   $this->paginate=$paginateOptions;
   $stuff=$this->paginate('Unit');
   $this->set('units', $stuff);



}

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally think there is a lot of overhead in the way you are trying to do this. The model is simple enough to call for pagination from the controller. My first choice would be to keep it in the controller. If the logic was more complex, I would say move it. But what you are doing is straight forward. Here is how I would do it in the controller.

```
<?php

function yourFunction() {
    $this->Model->recursive = -1;
    if ($paginate == 'true') {
        $this->set('models', $this->paginate(set_options_here));
    } else {
        $this->set('models', $this->Model->find('all', array(set_options_here));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I thought it would be simpler to do it my way, but I trust your advice, judging from your Stack Overflow points!  Actually, doing it from each controller method I don't need to do an if statement as I know I will or will not be paginating in each method.  So I guess I'll just keep doing my controller methods like I have been.  Could you explain to me a little as to why what I was trying to do is a lot of overhead?

Comment: Code becomes complex when you try to do more than one thing per function. Your model function was trying to do two things based on the information you were passing it. If you wanted to do that, you should really split those into two functions. For example you could name them `getAllListings` and `getPaginatedListings`. It would be very clear what each function does and the data you are returning based on the name alone. But have a function doing possibly multiple things just makes the code unnecessarily complex... in my opinion. Keep it simple and clean is my motto.

Comment: Someone advised me previously to keep 'fat models/skinny controllers' which is opposite of what I have been doing, mainly because the Cake manual does everything in the controller and because I'm so shaky with passing parameters correctly that I never seem to word my functions correctly.  Thank you for that insight.  I hope to run into more mentor types like you on SO!

Comment: Fat models and skinny controllers is definitely the way to go. But as you can see, the code in the controller cannot get much skinnier. ;) It wouldn't make much sense to call a single method in a model that will call another single method. The idea behind fat model and skinny controller is when the controller starts to do too much on the model side of things. But you will never get away from calling the model in the controller. So if they are generic find/paginate methods, just call them from the controller. I am always glad to help where I can. Happy coding!