# CakePHP Pagination. Keeping Model Fat

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-model

I currently have this in my Model (Referer Model):

```
public function getReferers($type = 'today') {
    if ($type == 'this_month') {
        return $this->_getThisMonthsReferers();
    } elseif ($type == 'today') {
        return $this->_getTodaysPageReferers();
    }      
}

private function _getThisMonthsReferers() {
    $today = new DateTime();

    return $this->Visitor->find('all', array(
        'fields' => array(
            'Referer.url',
            'COUNT(UserRequest.visitor_id) as request_count',
            'COUNT(DISTINCT(Visitor.id)) as visitor_count',
            'COUNT(UserRequest.visitor_id) / COUNT(DISTINCT(Visitor.id)) as pages_per_visit',
            'COUNT(DISTINCT(Visitor.id)) / COUNT(UserRequest.visitor_id) * 100 as percent_new_visit'
        ),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'user_requests',
                'alias' => 'UserRequest',
                'type'  => 'RIGHT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'UserRequest.visitor_id = Visitor.id'
                )
            )
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'Visitor.site_id' => $this->Site->id,
            'MONTH(UserRequest.created)' => $today->format('m'),
            'YEAR(UserRequest.created)' => $today->format('Y')
        ),
        'group' => array(
            'url'
        )
    ));
}
```

The thing is that I how I would paginate this. It will be so easy if just copy my code out of the model and to the controller. The thing is I want the keep the query in my Model.

How is this supposed to be done in CakePHP?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501849/paginate-from-within-a-model-in-cakephp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom find type is one method. You can find more information here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination

To turn your `_getThisMonthsReferers` into a custom find, follow this http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#creating-custom-find-types

For example:

```
// model
protected function _findThisMonthsReferers($state, $query, $results = array()) {
    if ($state === 'before') {
        $query['fields'] = ....
        $query['joins'] = ....
        return $query;
    }
    return $results;
}

// controller
public $paginate = array('findType' => 'thisMonthsReferers')
```

EDIT:

I think it should be :

```
public $paginate = array('thisMonthsReferers');
```

However the Solution I used derived from this answer is adding this to the method I am using

```
$this->paginate = array('thisMonthsReferers');
```

Since I don't want i used in all my actions. Then paginating the Model like this.

```
$this->paginate('Visitor);
```

Comment: I need to clarify things. In your answer, you mean to say that one option is to use #1 custom query pagination and #2 is to create a custom find?

Comment: No, they would be used together. You would create a custom find, and then configure paginator component to use that custom find for the query. First link describes how to configure paginator component, second link on how to create a custom find method.

Comment: About the custom query pagination. Wouldn't this override all methods on my Model? just a question.

Comment: It would change how you call them. Intead of `$this->_getThisMonthsReferers()` you would do something like `$this->find('thisMonthsReferers')` and your `public $paginate = array('findType' => 'thisMonthsReferers')`. You would then need to implement a `_findThisMonthsReferers()` method as outlined in the 2nd link above which would just be altering your current method slightly.

Comment: Your answer's probably better but I've solved my problem following Dave's answer. Thanks. I'm still getting my head wrapped over this.

Comment: Wow. after sleeping it out. I finally got how this custom finders and pagination work together.

Comment: Yea, `findType` was added in 2.3 (it's still beta though)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning the results of the find, just return it's array of options:

```
return array(
    'fields' => array(
    //...etc
```

Then use those options to paginate in the controller.  More details on this answer of this similar question:  [Paginate from within a model in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501849/paginate-from-within-a-model-in-cakephp)

It still keeps the model fat (with any logic that might alter the conditions, joins, fields...etc), and the controller skinny, which just uses the returned array as paginate options.

Comment: Yeah, I have thought of this option and was the solution I was about to implement. I just thought that there may be better options.

Comment: @ThorpeObazee - as you can see in that other question, I usually set it up so I can pass "'paginate'=>true IF I want the options returned instead of the results -that way you can use the function either way.