# CakePHP- Retrieve deep associative data

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have an issue trying to retrieve associated model data from another associated model.

I have `Donor Model` which is associated with `BloodGroup Model (belongsTo/hasMany rel)`. 
Now, I also have a `Donation Model` which is associated with `Donor Model (again, belongsTo/hasMany rel)`.

From the `Donation Model`, I want to retrieve data from the `BloodGroup Model`.

Currently only the Donor related data is retrieved. The idea is that I do not add a blood group field inside the donation, but map the blood group of a donation, on the fly, through the donor that made the donation!

I have been checking out the `containable Behavior` but I am not sure if this is how I can do it! It seems that it is used to 'contain' and filter data from associated models rather than to extend associations.

Any help appreciated very much, as always!

**[EDIT]**

DONOR MODEL

```
class Donor extends AppModel{
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'BloodGroup'=> array(
            'className' => 'BloodGroup'
        ),
        'DonorType' => array(
            'className' => 'DonorType'
        )
    );
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Donation' => array(
            'className' => 'Donation',
            'foreignKey' => 'donor_id',
            'order' => 'Donation.created DESC',
            'limit' => 10,
            'dependent' => true
        )
    );
```

DONATION MODEL

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'Donor' => array(
            'className' => 'Donor',
            'counterCache' => true,
        )
    );
```

From the Donation Controller :

```
public $paginate = array(
        'order' => array("Donation.d_date" => 'desc'),
        'limit' => 10
    );
$this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;       
        $donations = $this->Paginator->paginate('Donation');
        $this->set('donations',$donations)
```

Result retrieved :

```
[donations] => Array 
(

[0] => Array
        (
            [Donation] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [donor_id] => 4
                    etc..

                )
            [Donor] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [name] => ...


                )
        )
)
```

Comment: can you paste the code from the models? The associations. And the `find` calls you are using.

Comment: tried changing the value of recursive paramenter in your find call?

Comment: @cornelb I updated my question! 
arilia to what should I set the recursive? To be perfectly honest I havn't even used recursive yet, as I don't fully understand how its used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what data you actually want to get, but to answer what appears to be your hope:

> "From the Donation Model, I want to retrieve data from the BloodGroup
>   Model."

Because there's a related path, you can get BloodGroup data, from the Donation model like this:

```
$this->Donor->BloodGroup->find('all');
```

Or by using Containable:

```
$this->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Donor' => array(
            'BloodGroup'
        )
    )
));
```

There's a lot of options - it just depends on what data you need.

For details on how I use find()s in my Model while still paginating, see this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6577042/673664

(there are likely a lot of ways to do this - this is just the one I use, and works great for me)

Comment: Dave, thanks for your answer, I will try this out! my only concern is, can I do this with the paginate rather than the find()?

Comment: It seems, I am not able to accomplish this using the paginate() method! Any ideas? I do need to paginate my results though, so using find instead of paginate doesn;t really cut it for me..

Answer (score 0):

If the BloodGroup has many Donor and if Donor has many Donation, You can retrieve Donation data from BloodGroup but you have to set the recursive to 2 (`$this->Donation->recursive = 2;`) before you use `find` method. If you want output blood group data from donation. Try that.

Comment: Hi Miheretab! I am not sure if I follow! I want to retrieve bloodGroup Data from the Donation rather than the other way around! thanks