# CakePHP pagination in existing find() operations

Tags: ajax, cakephp, pagination, find, has-and-belongs-to-many

I thought a bit too late about the pagination in my cakephp project, so now I have existing (complex) HABTM find operations (with dynamic order, tag search etc..) is it possible to do a cakephp pagination at this point? Or is it better/easier to do the pagination by my own (find next 20 entries from ID xx...)?
I've searched a long time for a solution but actually i've found nothing useful

Comment: Hi did my answer work? What changes yoh made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what you do , how complex app you make , you just need some syntax changes to make pagination , I had same , please check the solution i implemented.

```
    $conditionSearchLessonsByCourse = array('CourseLessonsReference.is_active'=>1,
                                            'Course1.is_active'=>1 ,
                                            'CourseCategory.is_active'=>1,
                                            'Reference.is_active'=>1
                                            );      


    //Pagination logic
    $this->paginate = array('conditions' => $conditionSearchLessonsByCourse, 
                            'order' =>'CourseLessonsReference.id DESC',                             
                            'limit' => PAGINATION_LIMIT,
                            "joins" => array(
                                            array(//UserCourse = Course Join
                                                "table" => "courses",
                                                "alias" => "Course1",
                                                "type" => "INNER",
                                                "conditions" => array(
                                                    "Course1.id = CourseLessonsReference.course_id"
                                                )
                                            ),//For Category = Course Join
                                            array(
                                                "table" => "course_categories",
                                                "alias" => "CourseCategory",
                                                "type" => "INNER",
                                                "conditions" => array(
                                                    "CourseCategory.id = Course1.course_category_id"
                                                )
                                            )
                                        ),
                            'recursive' =>  2                               
                            );
    $allLessonReferences = $this->paginate('CourseLessonsReference');
```

Comment: hey yeah works like a charm thanks a lot! i combined it with this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6502142/4032742 .. but i keep having problems with the order of the pagination: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27512723/cakephp-pagination-keep-custom-order